# Insert, Delete and Update Commands are not built by the Adapter

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlcommand, dataadapter

I've built a connection with a DataAdapter to a .mdb file but the insert, delete and update commands are null and I can't use them.

Why is it like that and what's the solution?

Comment: can you explain the issue with some code sample you have used there

Comment: i build it by visual data adapter.i mean i didn't write codes. but visual studio didn;t creat insert command.

Comment: So what error are you getting and what are you trying to do now?

Comment: Did check the database conenction ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

To know this you should understand the difference between SqlCommand and SqlCommandBuilder .

A Command object is used to execute scalar or non query commands to a database. You would set a command objects CommandText property to and sql statement that you want to run and then use it's ExecuteScalar or ExecuteNonQuery method to run it.

A CommandBuilder object is used to automatically create Update, Delete, and Insert SQL statements for you, based on a Select statament that you supply. You would declare a DataAdapter object, set it's SelectCommand.CommandText property to your Select SQL statement. Then when you declare a CommandBuilder object, you include the dataadapter in the CommandBuilder's constructor parameter and it will automatically create the other statements for you when you run a DataAdapter.

example:

//save a record in a database using the Update method of SqlDataAdapter

```
using System.Data; 
using System.Data.SqlClient; 

class dd 
{ 
static void Main() 
{ 
        SqlConnection cn=new SqlConnection("server=.\SqlExpress;uid=sa;pwd=tiger;database=employeemaster"); 
        SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter("select no,name from employee",cn); 
        DataTable dt=new DataTable(); 
        da.Fill(dt); 

        //emp has 2 columns known as no and name. 

        //Initialize the SqlCommandBuilder. 
        SqlCommandBuilder cd=new SqlComandBuilder(da); 

        //create a DataRow 
        DataRow dr=dt.NewRow(); 
        dr["no"]=101; 
        dr["name"]="romil"; 
        //the row is temporarily saved 
        dt.Rows.Add(dr); 

        //save the Row permanently in database


           da.Update(dt); 
    }
}
```